# Why and how does this piece of Javascript Code print 6 five times on execution?

Tags: javascript

This is the piece of code,which on execution gives 6,five times in one second intervals. Can someone please explain this to me in detail?

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        console.log( i );
        }, i*1000 );
}
```

Comment: keyword: `async behaviour` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` is part of the closure of the `timer` function.
When the `timer` function is executed,
it will print the value of `i` *at that time*.
By the time that happens, the loop has already completed,
and so the value of `i` is 6.
For all 5 executions of `timer`,
so you see 6 printed 5 times.
What else would you expect?

If you want to print a count from 1, 2, ..., 5 with timeouts in between,
then pass the current concrete value of `i` into the closure,
using an immediately evaluated function expression:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function (value) {
    return function timer() {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }(i), i*1000);
}
```

Another equivalent variation:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  (function () {
    var value = i;
    setTimeout(function timer() {
      console.log(value);
    }, i*1000);
  })()
}
```

Notice in both examples that the variable `value` is defined in the closure of the inner function, and a different instance of `value` is created in every iteration of the `for` loop,
with the value of `i` at the time of the iteration.
This is the crucial difference from the code in the question.

Comment: i think he'd expected smth like `1, 2, 3 ,4, 5`